# How to validate string lengths?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implement validation in Doctrine. Doctrine by default inserts any size string. If it's too big, then it inserts first N characters into the database.

If the max column length is 7, then this happens:
To be inserted: 'www.google.com'
Result: 'www.goo'

How do I get Doctrine to come back with an exception? I don't want to hard code the maximum lengths in my validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine won't validate the string length, see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#column.
You should validate all input values yourself using validators before passing it to the Doctrine entity. What's the problem of defining maximum lengths in your validator?